# Derivation of the Fourier transform of the derivative of a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

In Rudin's book, the author says that the Fourier transform of $f'$ is $it\hat{f}(t)$, provided that $f\in L^1,$ $f'\in L^1,$ and if $f$ is the indefinite integral of $f'$. Thus, using the fact that $f$ is absolutely continous on any compact interval and the dominated convergence theorem, I derived the following:

$\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} (f'g)\mathrm{d}m = \lim_{\substack{ a \rightarrow -\infty  \\ b \rightarrow \infty }} [f(b)g(b) -f(a)g(a)] + it\hat{f}(t),$ where $g(x) = e^{-itx}$ and $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}.$

However, it seems that there should be another condition that $f$ tends to zero as $x$ goes to $\displaystyle \pm \infty$ in order to derive the statement. Can I derive this condition using the already mentioned conditions, or should the condition be mentioned independently? There are counterexamples where $f$ is continous and integrable, but does not vanish at infinity. Thus, I am thinking that the new condition should be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f \in L^{1}$ and $f' \in L^{1}$ and $f$ is the indefinite integral of $f'$ then  $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x)=0$. First note that $f(x)-f(0)=\int _0^{x} f'(t) dt$ so $f$ is bounded. Also $\int_x^{y} f'(t)dt \to 0$ as $ x,y \to \infty$ so $|f(x)-f(y)| \to 0$. From these two facts it follows that $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x)$ exists and the limit has to be $0$ since $f$ is integrable.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I did mention that explicitly. Read my last sentence again.

Comment: A final question for clarification. That f(x)-f(y) goes to zero as x, y goes to infinity implies that we cannot pick any two subsequential limits whose values differ, and therefore the limit must exist. Right? Provided that it is right, all is done. Thanks.

Comment: @metric Yes, that is correct and that is what I had in mind.